# Support Vector Machine on train and test

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, svm

I'm trying to run different types of SVM regression on my train and test datasets. All my code is working but I feel I'm not running it correctly due to getting an accuracy of >0.95 on both train and test which is too high for sure.

Below is my code for how I'm running the regressions. Data set is far too big to upload (10000 rows etc) but consists of all numerical variables which have been scaled.

I think I'm running the test on its own model rather than on the train model but cant work out how to change it. I imagine it's the same mistake of all types of SVM so I've just uploaded two ways I'm doing it for neatness.

I hope I've explained it well enough if not can rephrase.

```
##non linear methods
set.seed(123)
poly.tune = tune.svm(default_flag~., data=train, kernel="polynomial",degree=c(3), coef0=c(0.1))
#summary(poly.tune)
#train
best.poly = poly.tune$best.model
poly.train = predict(best.poly, newdata=train)
svmnonlintrain<-table(poly.train, train$default_flag)
##accuracy from table
nonlineartrain<-(svmnonlintrain[1,1]+svmnonlintrain[2,2])/(svmnonlintrain[1,1]+svmnonlintrain[1,2]+svmnonlintrain[2,1]+svmnonlintrain[2,2])

#test
best.poly = poly.tune$best.model
poly.test = predict(best.poly, newdata=test)
svmnonlin<-table(poly.test, test$default_flag)
##accuracy from table
nonlineartest<-(svmnonlin[1,1]+svmnonlin[2,2])/(svmnonlin[1,1]+svmnonlin[1,2]+svmnonlin[2,1]+svmnonlin[2,2])

##radial basis function
set.seed(123)
rbf.tune = tune.svm(default_flag~., data=train, kernel="radial",gamma=c(0.1,0.5))
#summary(rbf.tune)

#train
best.rbf = rbf.tune$best.model
rbf.train = predict(best.rbf, newdata=train)
svmradialtrain <- table(rbf.train, train$default_flag)
radialtrain<-(svmradialtrain[1,1]+svmradialtrain[2,2])/(svmradialtrain[1,1]+svmradialtrain[1,2]+svmradialtrain[2,1]+svmradialtrain[2,2])

#test
best.rbf = rbf.tune$best.model
rbf.test = predict(best.rbf, newdata=test)
svmradial <- table(rbf.test, test$default_flag)
radialtest<-(svmradial[1,1]+svmradial[2,2])/(svmradial[1,1]+svmradial[1,2]+svmradial[2,1]+svmradial[2,2])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me guess: this is a credit risk dataset, and you're predicting the probability of default (response variable `default_flag`). If this is like every other credit risk dataset out there, you have a very imbalanced response variable with a lot more nondefaults than defaults. I'll make another guess that it's more than 90% nondefaults.

If so, I can get 90% accuracy just by predicting everyone won't default. Of course, that isn't very useful.

Error rate isn't a very meaningful measure of performance for imbalanced data. Use another measure like AUC or the Gini coefficient,  or even entropy (binary log-likelihood).